# Get ip address of matching interface in powershell

Tags: powershell, ip-address

I am not familiar with powershell. I want to store ip address in a variable whose `-InterfaceAlias` matches `'Ethernet(\s+)'` any space after Ethernet. The below command gives all the list of interfaces which are of IPV4.

`Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4`

Not sure how to filter Interface name matches a space after its alias name and store that into a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in Windows 10 / Server 2016 you can use `Get-NetIPConfiguration` like so:

```
(Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet *").IPv4Address.IPAddress
```

Further details: [Get-NetIPConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipconfiguration?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to just use a space and wildcard in the `-InterfaceAlias` parameter:

```
$IP = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet *"
```

It is odd that the Microsoft documentation says the `-InterfaceAlias` parameter does not accept wildcards, but it works anyway. See [Get-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=win10-ps).

Answer (score 1):

In full:

```
$IpAddress = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 |
                 Where-Object {$_.InterfaceAlias -match 'Ethernet\s+' } |
                 Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
```